# Macbook Air M1 clean reinstall stuck without Macintosh HD

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, startup, apple-silicon

I am trying to reset a Macbook Air M1 and after I was stuck on some issue where I couldn't create the user during the setup process ([M1 Mac clean install, getting stuck at "Create a computer account"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408876/m1-mac-clean-install-getting-stuck-at-create-a-computer-account)) I followed the alternative steps to reset the machine with the `resetpassword` command but now there is no Macintosh HD drive anymore and I have not been able to get it back with any of the instructions I could find.

In the Disc Utilities I currently see the following after "show all":

Intern

- APPLE SSD AP0256Q Media

  - Container disk3

Image-Files

- Apple disk image Media

  - Container disk5

    - macOS Base System

Any ideas with what instructions I can get to the next step? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, you've got this fixed (after a year), but it's worth pointing out to any and all readers:

MacOS provides a method to erase the Data volume in **System Settings**. This is exactly the same as the old practice of erasing the disk and re-installing the OS -- except without the need to delete and re-write the OS.

The OS is now on a read-only, secure volume, so is guaranteed to be flawless. There is absolutely no point in wiping it, and this avoids any problems caused by erasing the container or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to keep any files or data currently on the internal storage, consider connecting another Mac and using Apple Configurator 2 to "reimage" the device.

Otherwise, run First Aid on both the APPLE SSD and Container items under Internal.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will have to try finding another mac because the First Aid approach did not help.